# How do I check the validity of a remote URL with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, http-status-codes

I know this will probably lead to a security breach, but is there a way in JavaScript to check the validity of a URL? This has to be done **in the client**, because I need to check whether the URL is accessible from it. Internal/external network differences apply.

I have tried to use `jQuery.ajax()`, but it won't work with remote servers, and also JSONP, but I can't expect a JSON response. In fact, I have to test any sorts of URLs, not only valid XML or JSON.

Basically, I need to check for a valid `statusCode = 200` or similar, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems it's indeed not possible, probably due to security issues.

The resolution to this in my case was to create a JSONP response in another server, and the script would simply make a request to it (JSONP allows cross-domain requests).

Thanks to all.